# Finding a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with this property?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is Riemann
>   integrable on every bounded and closed interval, such that the
>    function $$ g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto
> \int_{0}^{x} f$$ is not differentiable in at least one point.

I was looking for a function $f$ such that $g$ is not continuous in one point (and so a fortiori not differentiable). I wanted to pick $$ f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}:  x \mapsto - \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} $$ since then $g(1)$ would blow up. But I think this function $f$ is not Riemann integrable on every bounded and closed interval, since it is not even bounded on, say, the interval $[-1,1]$. So anyone have another idea?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, the problem statement is to be parsed as "is (not differentiable) in at least one point", instead of "is not (differentiable in at least one point)", right?

Comment: Yes! That is what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take the function $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$.  The integral should have a corner at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a good approach to this problem is to look for $g$ first, then "differentiate it" to get $f$.
Of course, you won't technically be able to differentiate everywhere (that's the point!), but it's a useful source of inspiration.

So we're looking for a function $g$ that is (say) differentiable everywhere except at a single point. How about $g(x) = |x|$? Can you find a good function $f$ now?

Comment: Why the downvote, if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

There are monotone functions that have a jump discontinuity at each rational number. Let $f$ be one of these. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on each bounded interval, and $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ fails to be differentiable at each rational.